# The various components of Chef

Tags: bash, chef-infra

Just getting started with chef and it looks like there are several components, which I'm finding rather confusing. They are all available for download via https://downloads.chef.io/

- `chef server` to manage the centralized chef server
- `chef client` to manage each node
- `chefdk` to assist in development of chef
- `chef "workstation"` - Not even sure if this is a thing, but I see it mentioned in various articles and tutorials. But it's not on the downloads page...

I stumbled across another site that suggested I install it via command line as follows, using a `bash` installation script.

```
curl -L https://www.opscode.com/chef/install.sh | bash
```

I ran it and it installed several utilities (`knife`, `chef-apply`, etc..) to my `/opt/chef/bin` directory

```
> ls -hlt /opt/chef/bin/
total 32K
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5K Apr 28 09:57 chef-apply
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Apr 28 09:57 chef-client
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Apr 28 09:57 chef-service-manager
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5K Apr 28 09:57 chef-shell
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5K Apr 28 09:57 chef-solo
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.6K Apr 28 09:57 chef-windows-service
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1.5K Apr 28 09:57 knife
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  732 Apr 28 09:57 ohai
```

1. What did I just install? Is that the chef workstation (i.e. plain old `chef`?). Or is it some odd subset/combination of the other 3 components?
2. If I download one of the other components (e.g. `chefdk`) from the Chef Downloads page, does it just add more binary executables in the same directory or does it nicely create a `/opt/chefdk/bin` directory or similar? I ask because I'm a little overwhelmed by everything it's install and am having a hard time keeping track of it. Would love if it were just one giant tool with various sub-commands.

Thanks!

Comment: I thought the question was about [chef the esoteric language](http://esolangs.org/wiki/chef) when I saw the tag.

Comment: No, see the tag wiki ;-)

Comment: FYI: ChefDK = Chef Workstation tooling. All Tools will be installed separately into their own /opt/<name> directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By curl bashing chef, you install what you need to run `chef-client` (so for your node), as well as `knife`, a utility to interact with the chef server (to run on your workstation).

ChefDK will install in `/opt/chefdk` (IMHO you could just have tried that instead of posting such a question). Besides all of the previously mentioned (Chef Server being excluded), this brings additional utilities for cookbook development, including [test-kitchen](http://kitchen.ci), [foodcritic](http://acrmp.github.io/foodcritic/) (both for testing) and [Berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com) (a cookbook dependency manager).

So while the chef package allows you to be used on your workstation, ChefDK is the recommended package.